# Use zend-decorator to format Zend_Form_Element_Radio in a table column with oher Zend_Form_Elements in rows

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-decorators

I want use *decorators* to format as table the following Zend_Form, placing a description in the first column **and** the Zend_Form_Element_Radio's options in second column **and** add 2 *select* in every row as you can see in the html example later.

**I need a concrete/working example.**

> FORM

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    const KIND_1 = 'dineer1';
    const KIND_2 = 'dineer2';
    const KIND_3 = 'dineer3';
    const KIND_4 = 'dineer4';
    const KIND_5 = 'dineer5';
    const KIND_6 = 'dineer6';

    public static $KINDS = array(
        1 => self::KIND_1,
        2 => self::KIND_2,
        3 => self::KIND_3,
        4 => self::KIND_4,
        5 => self::KIND_5,
        6 => self::KIND_6,
    );

    const DRINK_C = 'c';
    const DRINK_M = 'm';
    const DRINK_W = 'w';

    public static $DRINKS = array(
        self::DRINK_C => "cole",
        self::DRINK_M => "milk",
        self::DRINK_W => "water",
    );

    const FOOD_B = 'b';
    const FOOD_F = 'f';
    const FOOD_M = 'm';
    const FOOD_P = 'p';
    const FOOD_V = 'v';
    const FOOD_W = 'w';

    public static $FOODS = array(
        self::FOOD_B => "burger",
        self::FOOD_F => "fruit",
        self::FOOD_M => "Meat",
        self::FOOD_P => "pizza",
        self::FOOD_V => "vegetables",
        self::FOOD_W => "Wursterl",
    );

    public function init()
    {
        $_please_select = array("" => " please select ");

        $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);

        $input_lunch = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('lunch');  
        $input_lunch ->setMultiOptions(self::$KINDS) ;
        $this->addElement($input_lunch );

        foreach (self::$KINDS as $k => $_descriprion) {
            $input_drink = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('drink_' . $k);
            $input_drink->addMultiOptions(self::$DRINKS);

            $input_food = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('food_' . $k);
            $input_food->addMultiOptions($_please_select)
                ->addMultiOptions(self::$FOODS);

            $this->addElement($input_drink);
            $this->addElement($input_food);
        }
    }
}
```

> expected HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="/" method="POST">
    <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></td>
            <th>kind</td>
            <th>drink</td>
            <th>food</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Description row 1</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="lunch" value "dinner1"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="drink_1">
                    <option value="w">Water</option>
                    <option value="m">Milk</option>
                    <option value="b">Beer</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="food_1">
                    <option value="">please select</option>
                    <option value="b">Burger</option>
                    <option value="f">Fruit</option>
                    <option value="m">Meat</option>
                    <option value="p">Pizza</option>
                    <option value="v">Vegetable</option>
                    <option value="w">Wurstel</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description row 2</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="lunch" value "dinner2"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="drink_2">
                    <option value="w">Water</option>
                    <option value="m">Milk</option>
                    <option value="b">Beer</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="food_2">
                    <option value="">please select</option>
                    <option value="b">Burger</option>
                    <option value="f">Fruit</option>
                    <option value="m">Meat</option>
                    <option value="p">Pizza</option>
                    <option value="v">Vegetable</option>
                    <option value="w">Wurstel</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description row 3</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="lunch" value "dinner3"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="drink_3">
                    <option value="w">Water</option>
                    <option value="m">Milk</option>
                    <option value="b">Beer</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="food_3">
                    <option value="">please select</option>
                    <option value="b">Burger</option>
                    <option value="f">Fruit</option>
                    <option value="m">Meat</option>
                    <option value="p">Pizza</option>
                    <option value="v">Vegetable</option>
                    <option value="w">Wurstel</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description row 4</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="lunch" value "dinner4"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="drink_4">
                    <option value="w">Water</option>
                    <option value="m">Milk</option>
                    <option value="b">Beer</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="food_4">
                    <option value="">please select</option>
                    <option value="b">Burger</option>
                    <option value="f">Fruit</option>
                    <option value="m">Meat</option>
                    <option value="p">Pizza</option>
                    <option value="v">Vegetable</option>
                    <option value="w">Wurstel</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description row 5</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="lunch" value "dinner5"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="drink_5">
                    <option value="w">Water</option>
                    <option value="m">Milk</option>
                    <option value="b">Beer</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="food_5">
                    <option value="">please select</option>
                    <option value="b">Burger</option>
                    <option value="f">Fruit</option>
                    <option value="m">Meat</option>
                    <option value="p">Pizza</option>
                    <option value="v">Vegetable</option>
                    <option value="w">Wurstel</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description row 6</td>
            <td><input type="radio" name="lunch" value "dinner6"></td>
            <td>
                <select name="drink_6">
                    <option value="w">Water</option>
                    <option value="m">Milk</option>
                    <option value="b">Beer</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select name="food_6">
                    <option value="">please select</option>
                    <option value="b">Burger</option>
                    <option value="f">Fruit</option>
                    <option value="m">Meat</option>
                    <option value="p">Pizza</option>
                    <option value="v">Vegetable</option>
                    <option value="w">Wurstel</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        <table>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to use decorators to "_format in a table_" or to _format a table_? I'm confused by your wording..

Comment: @mmmshuddup I want decorate my Zend_Form to display as a table.

Comment: Ok, and the example HTML you provided is your desired end result after the decorator gets used?  Or is it the HTML that you want to modify?

Comment: @mmmshuddup it's the expected result. I know that Zend will add more attributes inside the tags and more tags inside the table..

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/8451723/212940

Comment: @vascowhite thanks, I comment directly your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a solution based on this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/8451723/212940

Your form:-

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    const KIND_1 = 'dineer1';
    const KIND_2 = 'dineer2';
    const KIND_3 = 'dineer3';
    const KIND_4 = 'dineer4';
    const KIND_5 = 'dineer5';
    const KIND_6 = 'dineer6';

    public static $KINDS = array(
        1 => self::KIND_1,
        2 => self::KIND_2,
        3 => self::KIND_3,
        4 => self::KIND_4,
        5 => self::KIND_5,
        6 => self::KIND_6,
    );

    const DRINK_C = 'c';
    const DRINK_M = 'm';
    const DRINK_W = 'w';

    public static $DRINKS = array(
        self::DRINK_C => "cole",
        self::DRINK_M => "milk",
        self::DRINK_W => "water",
    );

    const FOOD_B = 'b';
    const FOOD_F = 'f';
    const FOOD_M = 'm';
    const FOOD_P = 'p';
    const FOOD_V = 'v';
    const FOOD_W = 'w';

    public static $FOODS = array(
        self::FOOD_B => "burger",
        self::FOOD_F => "fruit",
        self::FOOD_M => "Meat",
        self::FOOD_P => "pizza",
        self::FOOD_V => "vegetables",
        self::FOOD_W => "Wursterl",
    );

    public function init()
    {
        $this->addDecorators(
            array(
                array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'forms/_form_test.phtml'))
            )
        ); //added as part of answer. Note all default decorators are still available.

        $_please_select = array("" => " please select ");

        $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);

        $input_lunch = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('lunch');  
        $input_lunch ->setMultiOptions(self::$KINDS) ;
        $this->addElement($input_lunch );

        foreach (self::$KINDS as $k => $_descriprion) {
            $input_drink = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('drink_' . $k);
            $input_drink->addMultiOptions(self::$DRINKS);

            $input_food = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('food_' . $k);
            $input_food->addMultiOptions($_please_select)
                ->addMultiOptions(self::$FOODS);

            $this->addElement($input_drink);
            $this->addElement($input_food);
        }
        $this->setElementDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));//added as part of answer
    }
}
```

As you can see it requires only two small changes.
Then you need to create the file `scripts/forms/_form_test.phtml` which contains:-

```
<form
    id='contact' 
    action='<?php echo $this->element->getAction(); ?>' 
    method='<?php echo $this->element->getMethod(); ?>'
>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></td>
            <th>kind</td>
            <th>drink</td>
            <th>food</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
        $elements = $this->element->getElements();
        $options = $this->element->lunch->getMultiOptions();
        foreach($options as $key => $option){
            echo "<tr>\n";
            echo "<td>Description row $key</td>\n";
            echo "<td><input type='radio' name='lunch' value='$option'</td>\n";
            echo "<td>{$elements['drink_' . $key]}</td>\n";
            echo "<td>{$elements['food_' . $key]}</td>\n";
            echo "</tr>\n";
        }
        ?>
        </tbody>
        <table>
</form>
```

The file `_form_test.phtml` is effectively your decorator for rendering the form. This is a very flexible way of using Zend_Form and I learnt how to do this by reading [this article here](http://www.wjgilmore.com/blog/entry/how_i_learned_to_stop_worrying_and_love_zend_form)

The default decorators, such as 'error' should still be available with this method.

On my system I got the exact html output you asked for. Try it and see.

Comment: "viewScpript" is an interesting good solution. In my real case I prefer my solution (the RadioTable decorator), but It's a new arrow in my solution quiver!

Answer (score 1):

This might not be the prefect solution but it might help you!

```
class My_Form extends Zend_Form
{
    const KIND_1 = 'dineer1';
    const KIND_2 = 'dineer2';
    const KIND_3 = 'dineer3';
    const KIND_4 = 'dineer4';
    const KIND_5 = 'dineer5';
    const KIND_6 = 'dineer6';

    public static $KINDS = array(
        1 => self::KIND_1,
        2 => self::KIND_2,
        3 => self::KIND_3,
        4 => self::KIND_4,
        5 => self::KIND_5,
        6 => self::KIND_6,
    );

    const DRINK_C = 'c';
    const DRINK_M = 'm';
    const DRINK_W = 'w';

    public static $DRINKS = array(
        self::DRINK_C => "cole",
        self::DRINK_M => "milk",
        self::DRINK_W => "water",
    );

    const FOOD_B = 'b';
    const FOOD_F = 'f';
    const FOOD_M = 'm';
    const FOOD_P = 'p';
    const FOOD_V = 'v';
    const FOOD_W = 'w';

    public static $FOODS = array(
        self::FOOD_B => "burger",
        self::FOOD_F => "fruit",
        self::FOOD_M => "Meat",
        self::FOOD_P => "pizza",
        self::FOOD_V => "vegetables",
        self::FOOD_W => "Wursterl",
    );

    public function init()
    {
        $_please_select = array("" => " please select ");

        $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);
        $this->setDisableLoadDefaultDecorators(true);

        $countRows = count(self::$KINDS)+1;
        foreach (self::$KINDS as $k => $_descriprion) {

            $rowForm = new Zend_Form_SubForm();

            $input_lunch = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('lunch',
                array('disableLoadDefaultDecorators' => true, 
                'label' => 'kind', 
                'label_placement' => 'prepend'));
            $input_lunch ->setMultiOptions(self::$KINDS) ;
            $input_lunch->addDecorators(array(
                array('ViewHelper'),
                array('Label', 
                array('style' => 'display:block;font-weight:bold', // just for this example
                    'placement'=>'PREPEND',
                    'tag'=>'span', //if you want to use other tag
                    'disableFor'=>true) 
                ),
                array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'rowspan' => $countRows )),
            ));
            $this->addElement($input_lunch);

            // add label just for the first element
            $drinkLabel = array('disableLoadDefaultDecorators' =>true);
            $drinkDecorators = array(
                array('ViewHelper'),
                array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
            );
            if ($k == 1) {
                $drinkLabel['label'] = 'drink';
                $drinkDecorators = array(
                    array('ViewHelper'),
                    array('Label', 
                    array('style' => 'display:block;font-weight:bold',
                        'placement'=>'PREPEND',
                        'tag'=>'span', //if you want to use other tag
                        'disableFor'=>true) 
                    ),
                    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td')),
                );
            }

            $input_drink = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('drink', $drinkLabel);
            $input_drink->addMultiOptions(self::$DRINKS);
            $input_drink->addDecorators($drinkDecorators);

            $input_food = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('food', $drinkLabel);
            $input_food->addMultiOptions($_please_select)
                      ->addMultiOptions(self::$FOODS);
            $input_food->addDecorators($drinkDecorators);

            $rowForm->addElement($input_drink);
            $rowForm->addElement($input_food);

            $rowForm->setSubFormDecorators(array(
                'FormElements',
                array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'tr')),
            ));
            $rowForm->setDisableLoadDefaultDecorators(true);

            $this->addSubForm($rowForm, 'row_' . $k);
        }

        $this->setSubFormDecorators(array(
          'FormElements',
          array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'tr')),
        ));

        $this->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'table')),
            'Form'
        ));
    }
}
```

Also, here are some resources to work with table and Zend_Form

http://www.packtpub.com/article/create-shopping-cart-using-zend-framework-2 
http://davidcaylor.com/2008/03/24/building-table-based-forms-in-zend_form/ 
http://blog.kosev.net/2010/06/tutorial-create-zend-framework-form.html

Comment: Very well played, but only in a perfect world. Unforunately my descriptions are of very different length, so the rows (with the select) are equally interleaved, but the radios and descriptions are not (equally interleaved).

Answer (score 0):

you do not can to do what you want accomplish with a view helper, in my view!

you should make a custom form printing, such as:

```
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <table>
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>kind</th>
            <th>drink</th>
            <th>food</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) : ?>
                <?
                $drink = 'drink_' . $i;
                $food = 'food_' . $i;
                ?>
                <tr>
                    <td>Description row <?=$i?></td>
                    <td>
                        <?=$this->form->$drink?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <?=$this->form->$food?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <? endfor;?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

`lunch` for the field, it is impossible to use it as you ask, you should think of another strategy. At the moment I can think of!

Comment: Unfortunately "lunch" is the most important field, note that I've a row for each "kind of dinner"! Further your solution is decorators-less and this is a problem. About the impossibility to do using standard decorator I agree with you, but I did't ask for standard decorators.

Answer (score 0):

Well here my version of the answer.

> Into the **init** I've add a custom decorator **RadioTable** to the form, and prefix path to load the decorator
>
> then I decorate all the elements as a normal table, this's important because all my efforts are to keep the facilities offer by standard decorators like "Error"
>
> Please note the **Custom_Form_Element_FirstSelect** and the **->setSeparator** in the radio element
>
> I also add the submit button

```
public function init()
{
    $_please_select = array("" => " please select ");

    // I add a my custom decorator
    $this->addPrefixPath('Custom_Form_Decorator',
                             'Custom/Form/Decorator',
                             'decorator');

    $this->setMethod(Zend_Form::METHOD_POST);

    $input_lunch = new Zend_Form_Element_Radio('lunch');  
    $input_lunch ->setMultiOptions(self::$KINDS)
                 ->setSeparator("\t__RADIO_SEPARATOR__\t")  //set custom separator I'll use in custom decorator
                 ->setDecorators(array(
                     'ViewHelper',  // add a standard decorator
                     'Label', // I'll use the label decorator to show text
                   ));

    $this->addElement($input_lunch );

    foreach (self::$KINDS as $k => $_description) {
        // to "mark" the first select I extend the Zend_Form_Element_Select
        // with Custom_Form_Element_FirstSelect
        $input_drink = new Custom_Form_Element_FirstSelect('drink_' . $k);
        $input_drink->addMultiOptions(self::$DRINKS)                    
                    ->setDecorators(array(
                                    'ViewHelper', // add a standard decorator
                                    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'),array('tag' => 'td')), // add a standard decorator
                                        ));

        $input_food = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('food_' . $k);
        $input_food->addMultiOptions($_please_select)
            ->addMultiOptions(self::$FOODS)
            ->setDecorators(array(
                            'ViewHelper',
                            array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'),array('tag' => 'td')),
                            ));

        $this->addElement($input_drink);
        $this->addElement($input_food);
    }

    // add a the submit button
    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
        $submit->setLabel('SUBMIT');
        $submit->setDecorators(array(
                                'ViewHelper',
                                'Errors',
                                array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', )),
                                array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr')),
                            ));
        $this->addElement($submit);

    // add the custom decorators to the whole form
    $this->setDecorators(array(
        'RadioTable',
        array('HtmlTag', array('tag' => 'table', )),
        'Form'
    ));
}
```

> the **Custom_Form_Element_FirstSelect**

```
class Custom_Form_Element_FirstSelect extends Zend_Form_Element_Select{

}
```

> the **Custom_Form_Decorator_RadioTable**

```
class Custom_Form_Decorator_RadioTable extends Zend_Form_Decorator_Abstract {

    public function render($content){

        $wrap = '';
        // I'll take the element
        $radioElement  = $this->getElement()->getElement('lunch');
        // then I render it and explode in array using the separator
        $arrayRadio = explode("\t__RADIO_SEPARATOR__\t", $radioElement->__toString());



        $count = 0;
        $arrayElement  = $this->getElement()->getElements(); 
        // loop on all form elements and I render them
        foreach ($arrayElement as $keyForm => $element){
            // I skip the radio element 
            if($element instanceof Zend_Form_Element_Radio){
                continue;
            }

            if($element instanceof Custom_Form_Element_FirstSelect ){
                // when I found the custom select element I'll prefix with "open-row-tag" and radio button in column
                $wrap .= "<tr>". "<td>". $arrayRadio[$count++] . "</td>" .  $element->__toString();
                // note that the select elements are already decorated
            } else if($element instanceof Zend_Form_Element_Select){
                // after the last select I close the row
                $wrap .= $element->__toString() ."</tr>";

            }

            if($element instanceof Zend_Form_Element_Submit){
                // add the SUBMIT button
                $wrap .=  $element->__toString() ;

            }
        }

        return $content.$wrap;
    }
}
```

Of course I can use the name of the element instead of use a custom element class to open the table row, but in this way I'm feel more flexible.