# Difference between Zend Form and normal HTML forms Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

Just wondering if there are differences between zend forms and normal html forms?

I came to know that we could simply add HTML forms in the view file and it works, however isValid function of form elements wont work for normal HTML forms. Are there any other differences?

I'm building a Zend Framework application for the first time and its quite hard to play with css in zend forms so I was wondering if I could use normal forms while using the features of zend validation like isValid?

Comment: You can use whatever you want. Zend Framework is just an scaffolding, if you don't want to use their specific components you're free to do so, but if you use their components then it will be easier for you to combine with the rest of the structure or other components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Zend Form manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.introduction.html)

> Zend_Form simplifies form creation and handling in your web application. It performs the following tasks:
>
> Element input filtering and validation
>
> Element ordering
>
> Element and Form rendering, including escaping
>
> Element and form grouping
>
> Element and form-level configuration

It is the third item `Element and Form rendering, including escaping` that gives most people trouble because of the markup generated, so they abandon Zend Form, but also have to give up the convenience of the others.

However, you can have the best of both worlds by using the viewScript decorator. My answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8451723/212940) gives an example of how to do this, so I won't repeat myself here.

Basically, Zend Form encapsulates form creation into a class to allow easy manipulation/validation. The form is provided with properties and methods that will make creating and manipulating forms easier.

HTML forms are just markup that has no functionality attached unless you write it yourself. Zend Form will produce that markup for you, or you can produce it yourself as demonstrated in the linked answer.

For further information you may want to read this article about [Decorators with Zend_Form](http://devzone.zend.com/1240/decorators-with-zend_form) by Mathew Weier O'Phinney, the lead developer of Zend Framework.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I'll use zend form element as they provide all the functionalities like validation, filtering, ordering, grouping. Thanks for you example link and mention the point.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to, you can mix them up.  You can add validation rules to elements, and elements to forms and validate against the form or each form element.  But you don't need to render the form (with the exception of a form with Zend_Form_Element_Hash or like.)

```
<?php

$form = new Zend_Form;
$form->setMethod('GET');

$e1 = new Zend_Form_Element('first');
    $e1->setRequired(true);
$e2 = new Zend_Form_Element('second');
    $e2->setRequired(true);
$submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit', array(
        'label' => 'Do something'
    ));
$form->addElements(array($e1, $e2, $submit));

if(isset($_GET) && count($_GET)) {
    if ($form->isValid($_GET)) {
        echo 'Valid';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid';
    }
}

?>
<form method="get" action="">
    First:<input type="text" name="first" id="first" value="">
    Second:<input type="text" name="second" id="second" value="">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Go for it">
</form>
```