# How to make a selectbox the label of a radio button in Zend Fw

Tags: zend-framework, drop-down-menu, radio-button, zend-form

Not my idea, but I need a set of radio buttons, where the last buttons value is a select box. Visual explanation:

o Opt 1

o Opt 2

o |___SelectBox|

What it would look like in HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="radioSet">Opt1
</input>

<input type="radio" name="radioSet">Opt2
</input>

<input type="radio" name="radioSet"><!-- Opt 3 -->
<select>
<option value="a"> aaa</option>
<option value="b"> bbb</option>
</select>
</input>
```

What I've done in ZF so far:

```
$picker = new Zend_Form_Element_Select('selectBox', array(
    'multiOptions' => array('a'=>'aaa', 'b' =>'bbb'),
    'decorators' => array(
        array('Label', array('escape'=>false))
        )
    ));


$this->addElement(
'radio',
'radioSet',
array(
    'multioptions' => array(
            'x'=>'Opt1',
            'y'=>'Opt2',
            'z'=>$picker //'Dropdown picker'
            ),
    'label' => 'My Title:',
    'decorators' => array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',
            array('Description', array('escape' => false)),
            'Label',
            array('HtmlTag', array('tag'=>'div')),
    ),
)
);
```

But this returns just the 3 radio buttons, as well as the labels "Opt1" and "Opt2", but nothing after the third radio button.

I WANT it to be like the HTML code shown above, but this ZF code does not return it. Anyone an idea how this can be accomplished?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to write custom view helper decorator?

Comment: I don't think you need custom decorators here, use a view script for the form instead. http://stackoverflow.com/a/8455360/212940

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your advices. I'm quite new to Zend, so I checked up how to make a custom view helper decorator, I couldn't manage to get it to work like that, but it helped me in another problem though.

I came to the solution, that it's easier to just add the select box as an individual element afterwards, and style it to the desired position with css.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately you probably going to have to write a decorator to replace the *label* tag with a *select*. Looking at the code for the Zend_Form_Element_Radio() it specifically adds the *label* tag to the radio.